# How to get the country code from a specific country in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a country dropdownlist now I want to get the selected countries country code. Like user select "The Netherlands" now I want to get the country code "NL" but I don't know how to do this. I am using c# for server coding.

Can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Dropdownlist.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: Do you have that code already? Otherwise add it to your database as column. Then you can make the `DataValueField`.

Comment: How do you populate your dropdownlist? From a DB, hard-coded, ...?

Comment: DropDownList on WebForms, WinForms. MVC, or ?

Comment: Actually my question is how to convert English name to ISO 3166-2 code. Like "United State" to "US" by using RegionInfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually my question is how to convert English name to ISO 3166-2 code. Like "United State" to "US" by using RegionInfo.

You can write a Linq to get a dictionary of `<name,code>`

```
var countries = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                .Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID))
                .Select(x => new[] { new { Name = x.DisplayName, Code = x.Name },
                                     new { Name = x.NativeName, Code = x.Name }
                                    })
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .Distinct()
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Code, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Now you can use it as

```
Console.WriteLine(countries["United States"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code...

```
  using System.Configuration; 
  using System.Globalization;   
        /// <summary>

        /// populate country name

        /// </summary>

        /// <param name="dropDown"></param>

        public static void GetCountryNames(DropDownList dropDown)

        {

            Hashtable h = new Hashtable();



            Dictionary<string, string> objDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (CultureInfo ObjCultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))

            {

                RegionInfo objRegionInfo = new RegionInfo(ObjCultureInfo.Name);

                if (!objDic.ContainsKey(objRegionInfo.EnglishName))

                {

                    objDic.Add(objRegionInfo.EnglishName, objRegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToLower());

                }

            }



            SortedList<string, string> sortedList = new SortedList<string, string>(objDic);


            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in sortedList)

            {

                dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(val.Key, val.Key));

            }



            dropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "Select"));

            dropDown.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Other Country", "Other"));

        }

    }
```

Call this function like this

```
PopulateCountryName(dropDownCountry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking just for

> using c# for server coding

and I'm assuming that you want just to map the selected option with the country code. The most simple way would be to use an [enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx), like so:

```
public enum CountryCodes
 {
     Netherlands = "NL",
     ...
     UnitedKingdom  = "GB"        
 }
```

and just get the code according to the selected option. Available [list of codes](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm) you can find on the web.

Comment: Enum name with a space in it?